# Strange behavior of regex in url adress

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this regular expression work? I use this part '\.' after '(.*)'
to show that I want to see the dot before 'net' and in theory it has to show 'null', but it gives the match.

```js
console.log('https://www.monet'.match(new RegExp(`http(s)?:\/\/(.*)\.{1}net`,'gm')))
```

Comment: You need ``<< String.raw`http(s)?:\/\/(.*)\.net` >>``

Comment: You need to double escape backslashes in regexes. Run `new RegExp('http(s)?:\/\/(.*)\.{1}net','gm')` by itself in a console to see the regex it's producing